# kernel version 440.31.0 does not match DSO version 440.33.1 -- cannot find working devices in this configuration

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, cuda

I am using **GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Graphics card** with **Ubuntu 18.04** version. I am getting below error.

`2019-11-24 21:36:48.694996: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1`

`2019-11-24 21:36:48.695789: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:318] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_SYSTEM_DRIVER_MISMATCH: system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination`

`2019-11-24 21:36:48.695814: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: <username>-Z390-M`

`2019-11-24 21:36:48.695820: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: <username>-Z390-M`

`2019-11-24 21:36:48.695858: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:200] libcuda reported version is: 440.33.1`

`2019-11-24 21:36:48.695875: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:204] kernel reported version is: 440.31.0`

`2019-11-24 21:36:48.695880: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:313] kernel version 440.31.0 does not match DSO version 440.33.1 -- cannot find working devices in this configuration`

I tried to upgrade the Nvidia driver to 440.31.0 from 435 variant which comes from the Ubuntu Distribution by default, but still getting this version mismatch.

Please let me know of the version which best matches both Nivida drivers and Cuda library. I am not able to use my Graphics card for Tensor Flow computation.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen the same error message and it was fixed by the following commands:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade`

Then reboot the computer.